# For-loop code not working

Tags: matlab, for-loop, iteration, coordinates

I have the following code but it is not giving me the values I want. The loop is not working. Basically, I want the variables J1, J2, J3, J4 and J5 calculated from each coordinates of Mx and My which is used to calculate P in an existing Simscape file. The first value of Length is 500 (with an increment of 10) and Prod_Length = J5-Length.

If P > 6000, then the next values of J1, J2, J3, J4, J5, Length and Prod_Length are calculated and P checked. This process is to go on until P < 6000.

The issue I am having is - it's only calculating my P based on the first values of Length and Prod_Length - without considering the increment of 10 for Length.

```
#1   for Mx = 50:50:500;
#2   for My = 50:50:400;
#3   [Mx My] = meshgrid(Mx,My);
#4   J1 = [sqrt((Mx-100)^2+(My-20)^2)];
#5   J2 = [sqrt((Mx-20)^2+(My-150)^2)];
#6   J3 = [sqrt((Mx-50)^2+(My-450)^2)];
#7   J4 = [sqrt((Mx-150)^2+(My-450)^2)];
#8   J5 = [sqrt((Mx-7000)^2+(My-200)^2)-100];
#9   %
#10   %% I have a simscape file that runs with the mfile to check the value of P
#11   while P > 6000
#12   Length = Length + 10
#13   Prod_Length = J5 - Length; 
#14   end
#15   end
#16   end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using meshlab like the following, it shouldnt be used in your 'for' loop. It takes in ranges to create arrays for the X and Y values. See [Meshgrid](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html):

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(50:50:500,50:50:400)
```

Comment: Hi Cody. Thank you for the prompt response. I changed my code as suggested to:

Comment: Hi Cody. Thank you for the prompt response. I changed my code as suggested to:  [Mx,My] = meshgrid(50:50:500,50:50:400)  and removed the 'for' leaving just the 'while' loop. When I ran the code, it prompted me to use (.^2) instead of (^2) in the J formulas. When I ran it again, it says parameter dimensions are not consistent. I wasn't getting that initially.

Comment: I think it's because the X,Y are generated in matrix form which is inconsistent with format in Simscape. For every Mx and My, the 'J' values are calculated and used as input parameter in the Simscape to determine if P > 6000 and if yes, the next values of Mx and My should be calculated and new Js calculated as well.